# PropertyChangedNotifier for Avalonia?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, avaloniaui

PropertyChangedNotifier is a basic function that is often needed in WPF to know when a DependencyProperty changed, [as implemented here](https://agsmith.wordpress.com/2008/04/07/propertydescriptor-addvaluechanged-alternative/).

Has anyone converted or written a similar function for Avalonia UI, or is there a built-in feature to do the job?

I'm trying to convert the code but it's relatively complex and converting it would require extensive testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
listBoxItem.GetObservable(ListBoxItem.IsSelectedProperty)
    .Subscribe(e => 
{
   // your handler code
});
```

Or just consume the observable via Reactive Extensions instead of just subscribing a handler.